# Combine "window.width" and "scrolltop" automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'am trying to combine "window.width" with "scrollTop" without sucess.
The goal here is:

1 - Verify the window width (<600, >600&<1000, >1000);

2 - Verify scrollTop;

3 - Change the class "div_reservas_container" to "div_reservas_container_fixo".

So far I've try this:

```js
var windowsize = $(window).width();

$(window).resize(function() {

      windowsize = $(window).width();

      // PC
      if (windowsize > 1000) {
        jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
          if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 485) {
            jQuery(".div_reservas_container").addClass("div_reservas_container_fixo");
          } else {
            jQuery(".div_reservas_container").removeClass("div_reservas_container_fixo");
          }
        });
      }
      // FIM

      // TABLET
      if (windowsize > 600 & windowsize < 1000) {
        jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
          if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 355) {
            jQuery(".div_reservas_container").addClass("div_reservas_container_fixo");
          } else {
            jQuery(".div_reservas_container").removeClass("div_reservas_container_fixo");
          }
        });
      }
      // FIM

      // MOBILE
      if (windowsize < 600) {
        jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
          if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 255) {
            jQuery(".div_reservas_container").addClass("div_reservas_container_fixo");
          } else {
            jQuery(".div_reservas_container").removeClass("div_reservas_container_fixo");
          }
        });
      }
      // FIM
```

Only works if you resize the browser width, I need it to work automatically.
Somebody can help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This script is an alternative to css STICKY who does not work on IE and SAFARI... also the website is responsive, thats why I need to verify window.width and strollTop.

Comment: you pass the function to `$(window).resize`, you need to give this function a name and put it at the end of the code, then pass this function to `$(window).resize` and call it out of `$(window).resize`.

Comment: Can you show me how to do it? I'm struggling with this script because I'am not an expert on JQUERY.

Comment: You only need one `window.scroll` listener/handler and manage different sizes inside it

Answer (score 0):

Just to help... the HTML:

```
<div class="div_reservas_container"></div>
```

The CSS:

```
/* MOBILE */
.div_reservas_container
{
width: 100%;
height: 60px;
top: 0;
left: 0;
margin-top: 315px;
background-color: #333333;
z-index: 888;
position:absolute;
}

.div_reservas_container_fixo
{
width: 100%;
height: 60px;
top: 0;
left: 0;
margin-top: 65px;
background-color: #333333;
z-index: 888;
position:fixed;
}
/* FIM */

/* TABLET */
@media screen and (min-width: 600px)
{
.div_reservas_container
{
width: 100%;
height: 60px;
top: 0;
left: 0;
margin-top: 435px;
background-color: #333333;
z-index: 888;
position:absolute;
}
.div_reservas_container_fixo
{
width: 100%;
height: 60px;
top: 0;
left: 0;
margin-top: 85px;
background-color: #333333;
z-index: 888;
position:fixed;
}
}
/* FIM */

/* PC */
@media screen and (min-width: 1000px)
{
.div_reservas_container
{
width: 100%;
height: 80px;
top: 0;
left: 0;
margin-top: 605px;
background-color: #333333;
z-index: 888;
position:absolute;
}

.div_reservas_container_fixo
{
width: 100%;
height: 80px;
top: 0;
left: 0;
margin-top: 105px;
background-color: #333333;
z-index: 888;
position:fixed;
}
}
/* FIM */
```

This JS script has been modified and improved by Илья Зеленько and works fine on Chrome (ok), IE (ok), Firefox (ok), Opera (ok) and Safari 5.1.7 (seems to read scrollTop with some gap):

```
var scrollHandler

myFunction() // calling immediately

$(window).resize(myFunction) // calling on resize

function myFunction () {
    var windowsize = $(window).width();

    window.removeEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler)

    // PC
    if (windowsize > 1000) {

        scrollHandler = function () {
            if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 485) {
                jQuery(".div_reservas_container").addClass("div_reservas_container_fixo");
            } else {
                jQuery(".div_reservas_container").removeClass("div_reservas_container_fixo");
            }
        };
    }
    // FIM

 // TABLET
    if (windowsize > 600 & windowsize < 1000) {
        scrollHandler = function () {
            if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 355) {
                jQuery(".div_reservas_container").addClass("div_reservas_container_fixo");
            } else {
                jQuery(".div_reservas_container").removeClass("div_reservas_container_fixo");
            }
        };
    }
    // FIM

    // MOBILE
    if (windowsize < 600) {
        scrollHandler = function () {
            if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 255) {
                jQuery(".div_reservas_container").addClass("div_reservas_container_fixo");
            } else {
                jQuery(".div_reservas_container").removeClass("div_reservas_container_fixo");
            }
        };
        // FIM
    }

    jQuery(window).scroll(scrollHandler)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You pass the function to $(window).resize, you need to give this function a name and put it at the end of the code, then pass this function to $(window).resize and call it out of $(window).resize.

Your code is very poorly read, so there may be a minor error.

I optimized your code and prevented the addition of unnecessary event handlers.

```js
var scrollHandler

myFunction() // calling immediately

$(window).resize(myFunction) // calling on resize

function myFunction () {
    var windowsize = $(window).width();
    var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    var reservasContainer = jQuery(".div_reservas_container");

    window.removeEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler);

    // PC
    if (windowsize > 1000) {
        scrollHandler = function () {
            reservasContainer.toggleClass("div_reservas_container_fixo", scrollTop > 485);
        };
    }
    // FIM

    // TABLET
    if (windowsize > 600 && windowsize < 1000) {
        scrollHandler = function () {
            reservasContainer.toggleClass("div_reservas_container_fixo", scrollTop > 355);
        };
    }
    // FIM

    // MOBILE
    if (windowsize < 600) {
        scrollHandler = function () {
            reservasContainer.toggleClass("div_reservas_container_fixo", scrollTop > 255);
        };
        // FIM
    }

    jQuery(window).scroll(scrollHandler)
}
```

Comment: Really bad practice to create new event listeners inside another event handler without removing any previous ones.

Comment: I made your code more readable and in my editor it does not give an error

Comment: this is a modern feature, it has [good support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=let), you can replace `let` by `var`

Comment: oh man... does not work anyway.... even if I resize the browser width... I'am really lost.

Comment: WOW!!!!!! Thank you so much Илья Зеленько!!! Thank you!!!!! Works perfectly!!! You are a lifesaver!!! I've tested on Chrome, IE, Firefox, Opera and Safari 5.1.7. Works fine in all browsers .... just Safari seems to read the scrollTop differently with some gap....

Comment: I have reduced the code even more and now it will probably work in a safari

Comment: You had this code:
 if (windowsize > 600 **&** windowsize < 1000) { it's probably a mistake, I replaced it with: 
    // TABLET
    if (windowsize > 600 **&&** windowsize < 1000) {